# I need to store two dynamic fields, i am getting error-expect parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php

```
    <?php  
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "table");  
     $number  = count($_POST["name"]); 
     $number1 = count($_POST["year"]);

     if(($number > 0) && ($number1 > 0)) 
     {  
        for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
          {  
            if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != ''))  
               {  
                $sql = "INSERT INTO input_field(name,year)
VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"[$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["year"])."')"  
                    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
               }  
          }  
          echo "Data Inserted";  
     }  
     else  
     {  
          echo "Please Enter Name";  
     }  
     ?>
```

Comment: print your query what the output?

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to put your content quality up

Comment: fix your bracket to this if(trim($_POST["name"][$i]) != '')

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <h2 align="center">Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</h2> 
    <!---Html form for dynamic fields--->
    <div class="form-group">
      <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <!--table with the dynamic field-->
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
            <tr>
              <!--add one row and two columns--->
              <!--Create the Name array-->
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="year[]" placeholder="year" class="form-control year_list" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    /**dynamic text box with remove button**/
    $('#add').click(function() {
      i++;
      /**append the dynamic fields,  declare remove button ++***/
      $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" />
     </td><td><input type="text" name="year[]" placeholder="year" class="form-control year_list" /></td> 
     <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    });
    /**write for click event-remove dynamic text box_**/
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#row' + button_id + '').remove(); /**remove table row**/
    });

    $('#submit').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "name.php",
        /**call name.php webform*/
        method: "POST",
        data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
        /** add all form data into array*/

        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
          $('#add_name')[0].reset();
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Here this is the form

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues -

1. is that correct value  - $_POST["name"[$i], should not it be $_POST["name"][$i]
2. If it's ok then problem is related to year field, you are using $_POST["name"][$i] as name value but using $_POST["year"] as year value. Instead of it use $_POST["year"][$i]
3. Lastly are you using array as your form field name ? you have not post your html form. If yes,then point 2 will do the job.

Comment: I have not found any form. can you please post it here or edit your question & add html form there?

Answer (score 0):

> Use this simple Code

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "table");  
 $name  = $_POST["name"]; 
 $year = $_POST["year"];

 $name=trim($name); 
 $year=trim($year);
 if((count($name)>=1) && (count($year)>=1))
 {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO input_field(name,year)VALUES('$name','$year')";
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))
               echo "Data Inserted";
    else
                echo "Error in Inserting";
}
else
      echo "Please provide the Data";
?>
```

Comment: thank u for answering, i tried ur code but it is giving an error 'trim() expects parameter 1 to be string'